# autocomplete does not display in Internet Explorer

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, css

I attended a video that describes how to implement a autocomplete in input. in the end I tested in firefox and chrome and it works well, except in internet explorer: here is the code below :

jquery :

```
function getSuggestions(value){
        if(value!=''){  
                $.get('suggest.php', {requestKword:value}, function (data){
                            $('#suggestions').show();
                            $('#suggestions').html(data);
                            doCSS();
                    });
        }
        else{
            removeSuggestions();
        }
}
function removeSuggestions(){
    $("#suggestions").html("");
    undoCSS();
}   
function fill(thisValue) {
    $('#ii').val(thisValue);
    setTimeout("$('#suggestions').hide();", 200);
}
function doCSS(){
$("#suggestions").css({
    'border' : 'solid',
    'border-width':'1px',
    'position': 'relative'
    });
}
function undoCSS(){
$("#suggestions").css({
    'border' : '',
    'border-width':''
    });
}
function addText(value){
        $("#ii").val(value);
}
```

css :

```
#suggestions{
text-align:left;
padding-left:5px;
font-size:14px;
}
#link:hover{ background-color:#f0f0f0; cursor:default;}
```

html :

```
<form action="/" method="get" id="set" name="set">
<input id="ii" type="text" name="q" size="96px"  value=""  onblur="fill();"  onkeyup="getSuggestions(this.value)"  /><br />
<div id="suggestions"></div>
</form>
```

mysql : 
suggest.php

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('keywords') or die (mysql_error());
$keyword=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['requestKword']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`.`keys` where `column` like '$keyword%' LIMIT 0 , 10") or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
    echo '<div id="link" onclick="addText(\''.$row['keyword'].'\')" ">'.$row['keyword'].'</div>';
}
```

Comment: what is the error you are getting?

Comment: there is non error, only on IE autocompletion is not displayed

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to consider jQuery autocomplete plugin here: http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/. It has nice working demo; tips ....

Answer (score 0):

Please see if this works for you...

Add these lines to your jQuery code:

```
$("#ii").keyup(function() {
  getSuggestions(this.value);
});

$("#ii").blur(function(){
  fill();
});
```

Replace the following HTML line:

```
<input id="ii" type="text" name="q" size="96px"  value=""  onblur="fill();"  onkeyup="getSuggestions(this.value)"  /><br />
```

with:

```
<input id="ii" type="text" name="q" size="96px"  value="" /><br />
```

Comment: Are you utilizing some script blocker such as Adblocker and/or similar? Not sure what is not working; but as far as jQuery can do with your code it work for me: IE9 64-bit. Just in case - I've uploaded changed jQuery code here: http://jsfiddle.net/salih0vicX/V77ek/; since it require external PHP file I was unable to set fiddle to work for you but you can use it to copy code localy and test it... Let us know about results...

Comment: the code is correct, i uploaded tow printed screen this one https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByVR0zenLDfhSFZaU05TLWt5WUk/edit?pli=1 describe haw autocompletion works with my navigators and this one https://docs.google.com/file/d/0ByVR0zenLDfhUDRQWWJzMElrSnc/edit for other autocompletion in Internet explorer

Comment: i think the problem come from CSS, i tried to add some css code : z-index with different values but it dosent work

Comment: What is your IE version? According to your screenshot it all works but the div is not visible?

Comment: i have the ie8 one, i tried also with ie7 and ie6 and the problem is the same

Comment: finaly i find the solution :)

Comment: if($result) 
    {
        while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
        echo '<div id="link" onclick="addText(\''.$row['keyword'].'\')" ">'.$row['keyword'].'</div>';
       }
    }

Answer (score 0):

finaly i find the solution, it very simple :

i add some sode in php code :

before :

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('keywords') or die (mysql_error());
$keyword=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['requestKword']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`.`keys` where `column` like '$keyword%' LIMIT 0 , 10") or die (mysql_error());
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
echo '<div id="link" onclick="addText(\''.$row['keyword'].'\')" ">'.$row['keyword'].'</div>';
}
```

after :

```
mysql_connect('localhost', 'root', '');
mysql_select_db('keywords') or die (mysql_error());
$keyword=mysql_real_escape_string($_GET['requestKword']);
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `table`.`keys` where `column` like '$keyword%' LIMIT 0 , 10") or die (mysql_error());

if($result) 
{
   while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)){
   echo '<div id="link" onclick="addText(\''.$row['keyword'].'\')" ">'.$row['keyword'].'</div>';
   }
}
```

Comment: It is good you found the solution. However, the way I understood your problem it was on client-side. Reading your post it is obvious you had issue with server-side script which I haven't tested since you never posted SQL script for the table in your database to speed up testing ... 

Anyway, glad you found it :)